# Can an instance method be a decorator to another method of different class

Tags: python, decorator

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a 


    def decorator(self, method):
        def wrapper(*args, **kws):
            if self.a == 'a' :
                return method(*args, **kws)  
            else:
                print ('cannot find attr a') 
            return wrapper    

class Bar():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        self.foo = Foo(b)

    @self.foo.decorator
    def method(self):
        print (self.b) 

bar = Bar('a')
bar.method()
```

In this case, I want to use an instance method to decorate another method in another class. Each of decorator or method to be decorated have to access some instance variable. So they cannot be separate from given class or even be a static method. Of course, my code doesn't work since I do not define `'self'` in @ sentence. Could anyone give me some advice to implement it or this is just a blind alley?

Comment: Would you be okay with just doing `self.method = self.foo.decorator(self.method)` in `__init__`?

Comment: You need to use `@Foo(some_value).decorator`, since you don't have an instance of `Foo` on which to call `decorator` otherwise.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve* here? The short answer is that instance attributes don't exist until you have an instance, which cannot be while you're still creating the class.

Comment: @TianchengLiu: Well, that’d be because the decorator is incorrect too; it should return `wrapper`.

Comment: @TianchengLiu you need to `return wrapper` in decorator from @Ryan suggestion.

Comment: @Ryan sorry for that mistake. Your idea works although it doesn't look like a decorator. I know this is how Python implement its decorator grammar sugar. But expand it make a little bit weird

Comment: It doesn’t look like a decorator because it’s not a decorator. You can’t use a decorator before it exists. If the result is a little bit weird, that’s because the goal is a little bit weird. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Exactly same on what I said. Actually the decorator should be some log feature like method to monitor a series method.